# Parse ticks to datetime

Tags: ruby

How can I convert a tick, such as `1298011537289` to a DateTime in Ruby?

The value I need to convert is coming from a JavaScript `Date.now()` call, so it's in milliseconds

Comment: You do realize that's over 40,000 years in the future, right?

Comment: Andrew: Those are milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

Comment: I thought he meant a POSIX tick, which is either 1s or 1μs. It's 1ms on Windows, sorry for that mistake.

Comment: Andrew: It's 100 ns on Windows.

Comment: Or 1ms depending ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time#Operating_systems)) :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-c-at):

```
myTime = Time.at(1298011537289)
```

or since you're using milliseconds rather than seconds:

```
myTime = Time.at(1298011537289 / 1000)
```

But that will only remove sub-second precision, to retain it:

```
myTime = Time.at(Rational(1298011537289, 1000))
```

Comment: You can use ```Time.at(1298011537289 / 1000.to_f)``` in order to not loose miliseconds precision.

Comment: @MichałZalewski You’re correct, and I’ve updated my answer to include it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use [strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and parse it with the format `%Q - Number of microseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.`

Example:
`DateTime.strptime "1352748750274", "%Q"`

Comment: This is the best way of doing it IMO. While working with dates that came as milliseconds from an 3rd party API, I had to setup testing and I found myself doing a lot of `(Date.today + 1.month).to_i` And then somewhere else doing `Time.at(fakedate / 1000)`. The downside on this is that Time.at will pick the Timezone you're in (At least while in Rails env). This method of parsing dates is clean and straightforward. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the value is in milliseconds, this is how I'd do it:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse(Time.at(1298011537289 / 1000).to_s) # => #<DateTime: 2011-02-17T23:45:37-07:00 (212164771537/86400,-7/24,2299161)>
```

Comment: Converting a Time to DateTime serves little purpose, as the main advantage of DateTime over Time is that it offers a larger range. However, it is also slower than Time.

Comment: It serves a lot of purpose when that is what the OP asked for. "How can I convert a tick, such as 1298011537289 to a DateTime in Ruby?"